# Sum unique character with condition

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements

I would like to create a sum on unique character with a condition.

This is my data test (.csv) :

```
 $ lot       : Factor w/ 3 levels "lot1","lot4",..: 1 1 1 2 3
 $ usl       : int  2 2 3 1 2
 $ site_value: int  1 6 1 2 4

lot  usl   site_value
lot1  2       1
lot1  2       6
lot1  3       1
lot4  1       2
lot5  2       4
```

I made this condition :

```
nbLotOOC<-sum(test$usl > test$site_value)
```

My result is 2. But I would count the number of lot that meets the condition. My result should be 1. I don't know what function or method use.

Comment: if you run `test$usl > test$site_value` you get `1 0 1 0 0` (with 1 =True, and 0 = FALSE). If you take the sum of this, you get `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
sum(tapply(test$usl>test$site_value, test$lot, FUN=any)>0) # or
which(tapply(test$usl>test$site_value, test$lot, FUN=any)>0)
```

From the comment of nicola:

```
sum(aggregate(test$usl>test$site_value, list(test$lot), any)$x)
```

#### data:

```
test <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"lot  usl   site_value
lot1  2       1
lot1  2       6
lot1  3       1
lot4  1       2
lot5  2       4")
```

Comment: @LaurentCesaro see the documentation of `tapply()` and `any()`

Answer (score 2):

You can find the indexes that meet the condition, select the lot column, find the unique occurrences, then check the length of that vector:

```
length(unique(test[test$usl > test$site_value, "lot"]))
```

Comment: What do you have as result ? I have 0.